# dragging audio files in specific order html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four broken parts of a music file.
I want to drag and drop the music files so that the files play in the give order. the idea is that the user has to drag the audio files in correct order.
I am able to drag and drop the music file, but dont understand how to set the source of the  to the src of dragged audio.

Here is the code :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#gif").hide();

    $("#play").click(function(){
        $("#span1").hide();
        $("#span2").hide();
        $("#span3").hide();
        $("#span4").hide();
        $("#gif").show();
       var one = document.getElementById("one");
       var two = document.getElementById("two");
       var three = document.getElementById("three");
       var four = document.getElementById("four");

       one.addEventListener("ended", function () {
           two.play();
          });
       two.addEventListener("ended", function () {
           three.play();
          });
       three.addEventListener("ended", function () {
           four.play();
          });
       one.play();
    });
});
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script>
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        console.log(ev);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>



    <audio controls id="span1" class="bg-info" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </audio>
    <audio controls id="span2" class="bg-info" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </audio>
    <audio controls id="span3" class="bg-info" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </audio>
    <audio controls id="span4" class="bg-info" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </audio>

    <button id="play">Play</button>
    <br>

        <audio draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="one" controls>
         <source src="PoetsOne.mp3"type="audio/ogg">
            </audio>
    <br>

        <audio draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="two" controls> <source src="PoetsTwo.mp3"
            type="audio/ogg"> </audio>
    <br>

        <audio draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="three" controls> <source src="PoetsThree.mp3"
            type="audio/ogg"> </audio>
    <br>

        <audio draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="four" controls> <source src="PoetsFour.mp3"
            type="audio/ogg"></audio>
    <br>

    <input type="button" value="Play Again"
        onClick="window.location.reload()">
    <img id="gif" alt="playing" src="sam.gif" />

</body>
```

it currently looks like this. I ca drag and drop the below audio tags into the top

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your drop function, as @Mouser said, get the path of the source element. Actually your data variable only contains the id of the audio element, so you will have to go to the source element since there is the src attribute that you need. So your function will be:

```
function drop(ev) {             
    ev.preventDefault();            
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");             
    ev.target.src = document.getElementById(data).getElementsByTagName("source")[0].src;
}
```

The bad thing about this is that if you have multiple source elements (for crossbrowser compability), you will pass the wrong source url since the element position is hardcoded. I suggest you take a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31114936/4637140)

Answer (score 1):

Omit this line

```
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
```

And replace with the following:

```
this.src = document.getElementById(data).src;
```

This will work because you are using a audio player as a valid drop target. So using the `id` of the dragged element, we can request the `src` from it and set it to the element in the `drop` event.